# If an element is in the closure of $A$, does that mean it is in $A$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

Recently I was reading the proof that the closure of an open ball is contained in the closed ball. It is a simple one-liner at the bottom of this page: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-closure-of-an-open-ball-and-closed-balls-in-a-metric-spa

However, I am quite concerned about the first implication as a closure, in my knowledge, is the intersection of all closed sets such that the open ball lies inside the closed sets. How can we make sure that if $x$ is in the closure then it is in the open ball?

Thanks!

Comment: We can’t: it’s not generally true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I am quite concerned about the first implication as a closure, in my knowledge, is the intersection of all closed sets such that the open ball lies inside the closed sets. How can we make sure that if $x$ is in the closure then it is in the open ball?

The proof in question is:

> Take $x\in\overline{B(a,r)}$. Then $x\in B(a,r)$. So $d(a,x)<r$. But this implies that $d(x,a)≤r$, so $x\in \overline B(a,r)$. Thus $\overline{B(a,r)} \subseteq \overline B(a,r)$. ■

You are correct. That first implication is erroneous, and this does not prove $\overline{B(a,r)} \subseteq \overline B(a,r)$. The argument only proves $B(a,r) \subseteq \overline B(a,r)$.

One way to prove it correctly is to show that the closed ball $\overline B(a,r)$ is in fact a closed set. Though "closed" is included in the name of the ball, we still have to use the definition of "closed set" to show that it is justifiable. How to do this depends on what definition of "closed set" you are using. Because of your definition of closure, I am guessing you have the general topological standard "a set is closed if its complement is open".

So if $y \notin \overline B(a,r)$, then $d(a,y) > r$. For $x \in B(y,d(a,y) -r)$, we have $d(x,y) < d(a,y) - r$. By the triangle inequality $$d(a,y) \le d(a,x) + d(x,y) < d(a,x) + d(a,y) - r\\0 < d(a,x) - r\\r < d(a,x)$$
so $x\notin \overline B(a,r)$, and therefore $B(y,d(a,y) -r)$ is contained in the complement of $\overline B(a,r)$. Since every point $y$ is the complement of $\overline B(a,r)$ has a neighborhood contained in that complement, the complement is open, and therefore $\overline B(a,r)$ is indeed a closed set.

Now $$\overline{B(a,r)} = \bigcap_{\text{closed }C\supseteq B(a,r)} C$$
But $\overline B(a,r)$ is a closed set that contains $B(a,r)$ and is therefore one of the sets in the intersection. Ergo $\overline{B(a,r)} \subseteq \overline B(a,r)$.

Note it is not always true that $\overline{B(a,r)} = \overline B(a,r)$. It will depend on the metric.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider real metric space with usual Euclidean metric, the set $(-1,1)$ is an open ball centered at $0$, you can easily observe that closure of the given set is $[-1,1]$. However $-1$ and $1$ are in closure but not in the given set. In fact we say $-1$ and $1$ are the limit points/accumulation points of the given set.

Limit points of a set are those points, for every open ball centered at that point, the open ball consists at least one point of the set other than the center.

In fact closure of a set is union of the set and its limit point set.